# How to display a Web Page's Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, stylesheet

Is there any way to display the FULL CSS stylesheet of a web page, other than fetching every style for each element like this:

```
document.write("width:"+document.getElementById("to").style.width+";");
```

The CSS can be in an external file, or inside `<style>` tag.

Comment: Do you need this for debugging or as an export of some kind? If it's just for debugging, you can view the applied and computed styles for any element in any good debugging console (e.g. Chrome, FF).

Comment: I am building a CSS Generator (border radius,triangles..etc) and I need to display the stylesheet of the generated element, many divs.

Comment: Ok, so, if your code is generating the css, why not just use that?

Comment: You mean use Javascript? There's lots of divs and it sounds a little bit crazy to traverse all of them and keep doing `\n` and `\t` and opening brackets `{` and adding `;`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you you're building a *CSS Generator*. So what is this generator doing? My thinking is this, if you have some code that has controll over the css code, then let this code export it. Instead of applying it to dom-elements and then re-extracting it from those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [document.styleSheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.styleSheets)

like in document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].cssText

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to use a server side language that can 'fetch' the CSS files and print them.

I have done this very easily in the past using Railo and a Java Library called jSoup. It's not a very popular setup, but jSoup can be used with Java (of course), so if you're using that in your web app, then it'd be a breeze.

I fetch my page in Railo like this:

```
<cfhttp method="get" url="http://example.com" resolveurl="true" result="local.objGet" timeout="10" charset="utf-8">
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="Accept-Encoding" value="*" />   
<cfhttpparam type="header" name="TE" value="deflate;q=0" />        
</cfhttp>
```

This code above makes a HTTP request to grab the HTML page.

I then use jSoup to traverse the DOM of the fetch CSS file links:

```
<cfset local.jsoup = createObject("java", "org.jsoup.Jsoup") />
<cfset local.getDocument = local.jsoup.parse(local.objGet.filecontent) />
<cfset local.getCss = reMatch('\bhttps?:[^)''"]+\.(?:css)', local.getDocument) />
```

This gets an array of links that end in '.CSS' from the document. I can then do a "fetch" on these again using HTTP request in a loop of the array. I can then print this to the screen and do whatever with it as needed.

I know that my answer is language specific, but the basic principles are there.

In PHP I think you can make HTTP calls using cURL, but once again, if you're using Java, ColdFusion, Railo or BlueDragon, you should be able to use jSoup just fine.

Hope this helps.

**Railo Application Server:**
http://www.getrailo.org/

**jSoup HTML Parser:**
http://jsoup.org/